# Acyclic graph - Smallest weight of each path between vertices

Tags: r, igraph

I am new to R and IGraph.

I want to obtain the smallest weight of all edges (can also be the label of the edge) from a node to another. But My actual goal is to perform the same for each node, which will provide me with all smallest weight in each path from each node to each other node.
*Edited*(graph is cyclic)
My graph is cyclic and undirected.

Example of my goal:

**Edges**

NODE1 > NODE2

NODE2 > NODE3

NODE2 > NODE4

NODE3 > NODE4

**Weight of edges**

EDGE1 - 2

EDGE2 - 1

EDGE3 - 0.5

EDGE4 - 0.2

**I want to get**

1 as result from NODE1 to NODE3

0.5 from NODE1 to NODE4 (one path)

0.2 from NODE1 to NODE4 (another path)

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

`get.shortest.paths(..., output="epath")` will give you the indices of the edges involved in each of the shortest paths that it finds in the `$epath` component of the result items. You can then use `min(E(g)$weight[some.path$epath])` to get the minimum weight in the path (where `some.path` is one of the paths returned by `get.shortest.paths`).

**Update**: okay, if your graph is not acyclic, there can be more than one path between any two vertices, and as far as I know igraph has no function for enumerating all the simple paths (i.e. paths without vertex repetitions) yet. The next major release (igraph 0.8) will have a function named `get.all.simple.paths`, which will probably do what you need, but it is not released yet so you'll have to compile it yourself from the development tree if you want to try it. Also, the API is probably not stable yet.

Comment: I have edited the question a little bit. In the previous case, it didn't show the edge with weight 0.2